# Tornado application ends after strating

Tags: python, tornado

I want to start my tornado hello world application. I've copied this code from tornado website:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When I try to run it int pycharm, a message says:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0

Comment: Works in PyCharm for me: the process runs until I kill it. I can visit `localhost:8888` and see "Hello, world". Are you sure you're running the correct script in PyCharm or are you running some other script, besides the one shown here?

Comment: if you just run the code on a simple double clic (on windows) or run it on shell on linux (python example.py) what it gives?

Comment: Are you running exactly this module, and not some stale configuration from a nearby project?