# Why is this code not working on windows, it works well on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code runs on Mac but doesn't work on windows. Im using pycharm (2019.2) as IDE and python 3.7.

```
import glob
import shutil
import os
dst = '/base/a/CAR1'
alter = '/base/a/CAR2'
path = '/base/a/Tub*'

for filename in glob.glob(path + 'Finsa*.txt'):
    if '19999' in open(filename, 'r').read():
        shutil.copyfile(filename, os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(filename)))
    elif '18888' in open(filename, 'r').read():
        shutil.copyfile(filename, os.path.join(alter, os.path.basename(filename)))
```

even if I do the following it doesn't work  -

```
for filename in glob.glob('C:/user/base/a/CAR1*.txt'):
    print(filename)
```

RESULT:
process finished with exit code 0.

Is this happening because python can't read the Windows file directory? I have tried everything including back slashes, forward slashes, double slashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0)

Answer (score 0):

Use the os module and place the base folder in your project directory:

```py
import os

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'base', 'a', 'Tub*')

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'Finsa*.txt')):
```

You gain portability between platforms (assuming both in Windows and Linux the base folder is in the python project space).

Comment: Thanks this worked. appreciate your help. This forum rocks