# Pycharm no output is showing in Console

Tags: pycharm

No output showing on my Pycharm Conole and showing error "The code is Unreachable" when hover on my print function

Below is output:

Process finished with exit code 0

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
    return num1
elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3:
    return num2
else:
    return num3

print(max_num(3, 4, 5))
```

Print function output suppose to be displayed.. No errors but "The code is Unreachable" is showing when i hover on print function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pycharm exit code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0)

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is working fine.
you can just use `print(max(4,3,6))` instead of defining a method `max_num`

```
print(max(4,3,6))
```

Comment: is it a problem with Pycharm IDE or what? I am unable to get output on my console?  I am getting following output" . "Process finished with exit code 0".. its happening to all my programs consists of functions

Comment: IDE is working fine the output to the console is giving maximum number. here is the reference to the same question asked before.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0

Comment: at given link example is different where user is getting output "hellow" then "Process finished with exit code 0" is displaying. In my case nothing output showing on my console except "Process finished with exit code 0".

Comment: your code is working fine. may be your pycharm IDE is issuing