# Python dictionary comes out with exit code 0

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a dictionary looking at a youtube video. I don't understand why it is coming out with exit code 0.

It should say November as it does in the video ?

```
monthConversions = {

    "Jan": "January",
    "Feb": "February",
    "Mar": "March",
    "Apr": "April",
    "Ma": "May",
    "Jun": "June",
    "Jul": "July",
    "Au": "Aug",
    "Se": "Sep",
    "Oc": "October",
    "No": "Nov",
    "De": "December",
}

print(monthConversions.get["No"])
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It should throw an error and exit non-zero.

Comment: @Sino Please make sure you're actually running the script you think you are running. There is no way this script will exit with exit code 0

Comment: If the answers below don't answer your question, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you executing this file?

Comment: rdas: What do you mean I am not running the right script? Maybe this could answer my question but I don't entirely understand what you mean.

Comment: What do you mean Caleb? I press the run-button in PyCharm :). I am a newbie

Answer (score 2):

use "()" parenthesis instead of '[]' while accessing the elements of dictionary using the get method. `print(monthConversions.get("No"))`

Comment: Not quite right, you use `[]` to access the elements of a dictionary.  But in this case `get` is a *method* of the dictionary, so it should be `()` to call the method.

Comment: It still comes out with "exit code 0" when I press run though. Even after changing the get and parentheses

Comment: it works for me. Can you please post the output as well

Comment: monthConversions = {

    "Jan": "January",
    "Feb": "February",
    "Mar": "March",
    "Apr": "April",
    "Ma": "May",
    "Jun": "June",
    "Jul": "July",
    "Au": "Aug",
    "Se": "Sep",
    "Oc": "October",
    "No": "November",
    "De": "December",
}

print(monthConversions.get("No"))

Comment: This comes after: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: are you using any IDE?

Comment: @Sino, are you using pycharm or any IDE?

Comment: I use Pycharm for this

Comment: @Sino check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645129/pycharm-exit-code-0

Comment: Ok, so everything is working well then? But the guy in the video is using Pycharm as well and his comes out with the month. I am talking about this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw . He is talking about dictionaries around 2,10 into the video. And his comes out with a month when he runs it. I thought I was doing the exact same thing he does. So why is mine coming out with "process end with 0"? :)

Answer (score 0):

The `get` attribute uses `(`, and not `[`

```
print(monthConversions.get("No"))
```